# how to get the next index array when button clicked

Tags: java, netbeans

```
String [] num ={ "one", "two", "three", "four", "five" };

private void btn_goActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    for(int i=0 ; i<=num.length ; i++){            
        label1.setText(num[i]);
    } 
}
```

It is just setting the text to last array element: `five`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are iterating in your function until it reaches the last index of your array.

You need to get the index of your label text with existing values in your array and reset the index if no values found or if index is the last one. i.e. :

```
private static JLabel label1 = new JLabel();
private static final String[] num = { "one", "two", "three", "four", "five" };
private void btn_goActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // Fetch index of label value
    int index = Arrays.asList(num).indexOf(label1.getText());
    /*
     * If no values found, index == -1, index + 1 will reset at the first 
     * index so we don't care about this case.
     * If index + 1 exceed array length, index is set to 0.
     */
    label1.setText(index + 1 > num.length ? num[0] : num[index + 1]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

He dosn't take the "five" directly but it's the last. 
Before the value was "one", then "two"... then "five"
you have to do something like that :

```
String [] num ={ "one", "two", "three", "four", "five" };
static int i=0;
private void btn_goActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    if(i<num.length()){
       label1.setText(num[i]);
       i=i+1;
    }
}
```

Here every times you clique on the button, the label change and takes the next value if it's available